# Quais são as licenças de software adotadas atualmente, e qual seu uso mais indicado?

Tags: licença

Posso dizer que amadureci como profissional na era do GNU, quando a Licença de Uso de Software GPL estava sendo amadurecida e amplamente sendo adotada para uso com softwares abertos e gratuitos, porém nos tempos atuais (no meado da década, no ano de 2015) temos diversas novas licenças, sendo as mais conhecidas:

- GPL e sua variação LGPL,
- BSD,
- Criative Commons, a mais citada no momento,

Como tais licenças devem ser aplicadas na atual versão, quais seus benefícios (de forma resumida) e quais outras estão em voga e sendo aplicada?

Comment: [Em português](http://escolhaumalicenca.com.br/).

Comment: Boa leitura: http://www.teses.usp.br/teses/disponiveis/45/45134/tde-14032012-003454/publico/MestradoVanessaSabino.pdf