# Como funciona o licenciamento de software no Brasil?

Tags: licença, brasil

O que é importante saber antes de licenciar um programa de computador  no Brasil?

Eu realmente preciso utilizar uma licença?

O que é e como funciona o sistema de software livre?

Comment: +1 isso é muito importante de se saber

Comment: me parece equivalente a pergunta que fiz e mais ampla ainda devido a abranger a questão de como funciona  um software livre no mesmo contexto, segue minha pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/69051/8039

Comment: @seamusd qual o sentido de editar uma pergunta apenas para capitalizar uma letra que, ao menos na minha opinião, nada melhora a pergunta?

Comment: @diegofm você tem razão, porém a pergunta não foi marcada como correta ainda. Então pensei em reviver porque talvez, eu digo talvez, alguém tenha uma resposta melhor que satisfaça a dúvida do autor dá questão.

Comment: @seamusd bom, para isso basta comentar e citar o OP para informar-lo que pode aceitar uma das perguntas. :) "Bumpear" várias perguntas para essa finalidade pode ser visto como mau uso do recurso de edição.

Comment: @diegofm eu conheço as regras básicas de previlegio de edição do SOpt, então vou evitar de fazer edições mínimas que não sejam triviais para melhoria da questão. Abs

Comment: @seamusd e no caso é uma edição errada, _software_ não é nome próprio para se grafar com maiúscula, reverti a edição. Mesmo se entendesse a expressão "Software Livre" como nome próprio, seria o caso de grafar as duas palavras em maiúscula, e não só _software_. Uma outra dica é sempre olhar tudo que precisa de melhoria, se for realmente mexer.

Comment: Paralelamente a isso, eu acho meio arriscado um post desses, pois o público alvo do site não costuma ter o preparo jurídico necessário para responder ou avaliar o assunto (o fato de o Gustavo ser advogado é um "bônus", isso não pode mudar o escopo do site). Uma resposta para isto precisa ser muito bem fundamentada para ter algum valor.

Comment: +1 @Bacco Foi por isso que coloquei um grande aviso no começo da resposta, e postei como wiki da comunidade. Esta resposta foi uma forma que encontrei de agradecer a comunidade, porque eu já tinha feito a pesquisa para o meu caso específico, e tinha reunido muita informação... então como **está no escopo do site**, eu *arrisquei postar* e foi bem aceito. De qualquer forma você tem razão sobre possivelmente não ter mais ninguém qualificado pra validar a resposta, o que realmente é complicado imo.

Comment: Seria legal se eventualmente programadores que consultarem esta resposta para um **esclarecimento inicial**, e posteriormente consultassem um advogado para analisar algo correspondente ao constante aqui, pudessem vir e corrigir eventuais erros/imprecisões (que podem sim existir).

Comment: De qualquer forma, se a comunidade achar que este post é inviável pelo fato mesmo de possivelmente não existir ninguém que possa validar, eu não me oponho a que seja removido. Acho que até já tem um post no meta sobre este tópico, vou dar uma olhada e posto aqui.

Comment: Não achei, acho que estava pensando neste http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3947/est%C3%A1-pergunta-est%C3%A1-dentro-ou-fora-do-escopo-do-site/3965#3965. Se quiser abre lá que depois faço uma resposta quando der... Abraços!

Comment: @gustavox não acho necessário, em princípio só acho perigoso o precedente.Talvez com o tempo seja o caso de migrar ou repostar ela para o Documentation. O fato de ser Wiki e o aviso no começo com certeza ajudou ela a sobreviver, só comentei no sentido de que tenha algo registrado aqui caso alguém amanhã ou depois tenha alguma pergunta similar fechada. Notar que eu mencionei da fundamentação num comentário mais acima, que também é um ponto que faz diferença no sentido de ser uma "exceção aceita". Desde que as pessoas entendam que é uma exceção ;) - é um "fora de escopo útil e bem feito".

Comment: Então, legal, e eu achei positivo ter este contraponto aqui, fica ainda mais claro que esta não é uma resposta no padrão SOpt (que em geral é validada pela comunidade, com muitos especialistas analisando, o que não ocorre aqui)... Eu realmente concordo com você, e isso é algo que até me preocupa um pouco, porque algumas pessoas podem pensar que com tantos votos aqui no site, então a solução para as dúvidas dela está aqui... é complicado mesmo... btw, gostei da ideia do documentation... de repente uma divisão jurídica da SE podia pegar o texto e passar por um crivo, reescrever... eu ia adorar

Answer (score 54):

> **AVISO**: Este wiki da comunidade não está 100% pronto, e até por sua natureza [wiki](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki), jamais estará. Foi escrito originalmente à partir de uma extensa pesquisa realizada por um advogado (o autor da pergunta, alguém que ainda está aprendendo a programar, com a inestimável ajuda do SOpt), mas **não por um especialista neste tema específico**. Havendo dúvidas, sempre é interessante procurar um advogado especializado no assunto, de sua confiança, e submeter seu caso específico a uma rigorosa análise. Você é convidado a editar este texto se encontrar qualquer imprecisão (mesmo a menor correção ortográfica ou gramatical), ou a incluir qualquer conteúdo que possa acrescentar informações relevantes. Para fazer isso, basta clicar em "Editar", no final deste wiki.

## Introdução

Esta pesquisa surgiu em decorrência da tentativa de responder [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69051/quais-s%C3%A3o-as-licen%C3%A7as-de-software-adotadas-atualmente-e-qual-seu-uso-mais-indic) de forma satisfatória, mas como a resposta foi ficando grande demais, pela necessidade de explicar uma série de conceitos sem os quais seria impossível entender o que são, e, principalmente, **onde** atuam as licenças de software livre, decidi então publicar um estudo mais detalhado como wiki da comunidade.

Para entender corretamente como funcionam as licenças de software livre, quais os direitos que elas realmente *suavizam*, e onde especificamente atuam, é necessário fixar antes quatro conceitos muito importantes (tentei utilizar o mínimo de termos jurídicos, mas em alguns casos foi impossível...):

> - programa de computador
> - patente
> - direito autoral
> - domínio público.

Então vamos a eles:

## Programa de computador

A definição encontra-se na Lei [9.609/98](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/leis/l9609.htm):

> Art. 1º Programa de computador é a **expressão de um conjunto organizado de instruções em linguagem natural ou codificada, contida em suporte físico de qualquer natureza, de emprego necessário em máquinas automáticas de tratamento da informação, dispositivos, instrumentos ou equipamentos periféricos, baseados em técnica digital ou análoga, para fazê-los funcionar de modo e para fins determinados.**

Analisar profundamente esta definição daria um artigo inteiro, então, simplificando: qualquer `Hello Word` da vida é um programa de computador para a definição legal (preciso verificar isso - e outras coisas - então quem puder colaborar, fique à vontade pra editar este wiki).

O programa de computador pode ser [registrado no INPI](http://www.inpi.gov.br/menu-servicos/programa-de-computador/guia-basico-de-programa-de-computador), para atestar  a autoria.

## Patente

A [patente](http://www.inpi.gov.br/menu-servicos/patente) é uma concessão pública, que garante ao seu titular a exclusividade para explorar comercialmente uma inovação tecnológica.

O INPI **não** realiza o registro de patente de software "puro". O registro é possível apenas como forma de se resguardar em disputas judiciais frente à terceiros, mas não garante a exclusividade na exploração de uma inovação tecnológica.

Isto porque a [Lei 9.279/96](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/leis/L9279.htm) (Lei da Propriedade Industrial) estabelece expressamente que:

> **Art. 10. Não se considera invenção nem modelo de utilidade:**
>
> **V -  programas de computador em si;**

Em 2012, inclusive, o INPI abriu uma consulta pública sobre patentes que envolvessem programas de computador, mas até onde sei [a ideia não foi para frente após ter recebido uma série de críticas](http://gizmodo.uol.com.br/inpi-nao-dara-patentes-para-software-diz-diretor-do-instituto/). No próprio site do INPI, na seção onde se realiza o registro de programas de computador, consta apenas a possibilidade de registro para “garantir maior segurança”, e não de patente.

Isso quer dizer que se você criou uma funcionalidade diferente para um programa que tem vários concorrentes no mercado, você **não** terá exclusividade sobre ela. Seus concorrentes podem imediatamente inserir a mesma funcionalidade, desde que tenham a tecnologia (e a criatividade, se o caso) para isso.

O que eles não podem, como veremos adiante, é pegar o **seu** código (por vias legais - simplesmente abrindo o fonte numa página HTML - ou não - roubando mesmo) sem sua autorização, e colocar pra funcionar no concorrente. Mas eles podem, ao ver a funcionalidade no seu site, criar uma igual por meios próprios.

A única exceção é quando o software é associado de forma íntima a um hardware determinado, e dele dependente (também precisamos nos aprofundar sobre isso) por exemplo XXXXX). Contudo, de qualquer forma, na prática a patente que se registra é do hardware, incluindo um software específico associado àquele hardware.

> **Simplificando: em geral você pode copiar qualquer ideia/inovação de um software (mas aconselho que você nem veja os fontes!), e pode ser copiado.**

## Direito autoral

É o conjunto de direitos de um autor sobre a obra de sua criação. No Brasil, é regido pela Lei 9.610/98, a qual inclui expressamente “os programas de computador” como obra protegida (art. 7, inc. XII).

Desde que o Superior Tribunal de Justiça reconheceu a natureza jurídica de propriedade intelectual (e não industrial) para os programas de computador ([REsp n.º 443.119/2003](https://ww2.stj.jus.br/processo/pesquisa/?tipoPesquisa=tipoPesquisaNumeroRegistro&termo=200200712817&totalRegistrosPorPagina=40&aplicacao=processos.ea)), uma sólida [corrente jurisprudencial](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jurisprud%C3%AAncia) se formou neste sentido, afirmando que o programa de computador tem natureza jurídica de direito autoral, aplicando -se a ele o mesmo regime jurídico das obras literárias.

Então é justamente no âmbito do direito autoral que as licenças incidem; elas não fazem nenhuma diferença no quesito exclusividade (patente) aqui no Brasil (onde você não a terá de qualquer jeito).

Então, quando você cria um ”programa de computador” (qualquer `Hello word!` da  vida), sua criação está protegida pelas leis 9.610/98 e 9.609/98.

E isso mesmo sem você ter realizado nenhum registro, independentemente de sua vontade:

> **Art. 18. A proteção aos direitos de que trata esta Lei independe de registro.**

O registro no INPI pode ser importante para provar a autoria do programa, mas segundo a Lei é apenas uma opção:

> **Art. 19. É facultado ao autor registrar a sua obra no órgão público definido no caput e no § 1º do art. 17 da Lei nº 5.988, de 14 de dezembro de 1973.**

Existem outras formas possíveis de se provar a autoria de um programa - há quem diga que basta enviar um simples e-mail para si mesmo - mas você pode registrar até em papel num cartório (provando assim a data de publicação e a autoria), ou mesmo simplesmente hospedar num servidor estabelecido e confiável (que eventualmente poderá atestar em juízo a data que os arquivos foram enviados para o servidor).

Porém, como não fica tão caro (relativamente), acredito que o mais indicado seja registrar pelo INPI, já que o Decreto Regulamentador 2256/98 estabeleceu especificamente que:

> **“Art. 1º Os programas de computador poderão, a critério do titular dos respectivos direitos, ser registrados no Instituto Nacional da Propriedade Industrial - INPI.”.**

E quais direitos estão reservados?

A lei divide os direitos de autor em morais e patrimoniais. Os direitos morais são irrenunciáveis e inalienáveis (veja todos os direitos morais do autor no art. 24 da Lei 9.610/98.)

No entanto, no caso específico dos programas de computador, a Lei 9.609/98 manteve apenas dois dos direitos morais do autor:

> § 1º Não se aplicam ao programa de computador as disposições relativas aos direitos morais, **ressalvado, a qualquer tempo, o direito do autor de reivindicar a paternidade do programa de computador e o direito do autor de opor-se a alterações não-autorizadas, quando estas impliquem deformação, mutilação ou outra modificação do programa de computador, que prejudiquem a sua honra ou a sua reputação.**
>   (O final deste parágrafo lembra muito a licença BSD, como veremos adiante)

Dentre os direitos patrimoniais do autor (Lei 9.610/98) estão:

> Art. 29. Depende de **autorização prévia e expressa** do autor a utilização da obra, por quaisquer modalidades, tais como:
>  **I - a
>   reprodução parcial ou integral;
>  II - a edição; [...] 
> VI - a
>   distribuição, quando não intrínseca ao contrato firmado pelo autor com
>   terceiros para uso ou exploração da obra; 
> VII - a distribuição para
>   oferta de obras ou produções mediante cabo, fibra ótica, satélite,
>   ondas ou qualquer outro sistema que permita ao usuário realizar a
>   seleção da obra ou produção para percebê-la em um tempo e lugar
>   previamente determinados por quem formula a demanda, e nos casos em
>   que o acesso às obras ou produções se faça por qualquer sistema que
>   importe em pagamento pelo usuário;**

“Cereja no bolo” da proteção ao direito autoral do programa de computador são as implicações criminais:

> Art. 12. Violar direitos de autor de programa de computador: 
> Pena -
>   Detenção de **seis meses a dois anos ou multa**. 
> § 1º **Se** a violação
>   consistir na reprodução, por qualquer meio, de programa de computador,
>   no todo ou em parte, **para fins de comércio**, sem autorização expressa
>   do autor ou de quem o represente: 
> Pena - Reclusão de **um a quatro anos
>   e multa**.
>  § 2º Na **mesma pena** do parágrafo anterior incorre quem **vende,
>   expõe à venda, introduz no País, adquire, oculta ou tem em depósito,
>   para fins de comércio, original ou cópia de programa de computador,
>   produzido com violação de direito autoral.**

Assim, e resumidamente (o tanto quanto possível) são estes os direitos que as licenças de software livre pretendem “suavizar”.

Para ter estes direitos você não precisa fazer nada, não sendo necessário nenhum tipo de registro para ter os direitos resguardados (mas havendo disputa de autoria você será uma pessoa mais feliz se tiver feito o registro ;) ).

Então, neste extremo temos a licença proprietária, com todos os direitos reservados ©, previsão de guerras cataclísmicas no Tribunais para atestar a “paternidade de um software” (o que no Brasil ainda engatinha, mas que nos EUA já é uma indústria), pessoas processadas criminalmente, estagnação de tecnologia...

Mas que compra o leite das crianças. :-)

## Domínio público

No outro extremo está a disponibilização por domínio público, em que absolutamente nenhum direito é reservado, nem mesmo de citação do autor original.

Há pouco leite para as crianças aqui, porém:

> **O domínio público é a base da nossa auto-compreensão, expressa pelo nosso conhecimento e cultura compartilhados. É a matéria-prima da qual são derivados os novos conhecimentos e criadas as novas obras culturais. O domínio público atua como um mecanismo de proteção para garantir que essa matéria-prima esteja disponível ao custo de sua reprodução – próximo de zero – e que todos os membros da sociedade possam construir com base neste conteúdo.** ([O Manifesto do Domínio Público](http://direitorio.fgv.br/sites/direitorio.fgv.br/files/Manifesto%20do%20Dominio%20Publico%20-%20Portuguese%20Version_0.pdf))

O domínio público é inevitável após certo tempo da morte do autor (aqui no Brasil 70 anos desde a morte, e no caso de programas de computador, de 50 anos desde o primeiro dia do ano seguinte à publicação, ou da criação, se não for publicado).

O programa de computador, inclusive, não é definido como bem público ou particular; observa ele uma natureza mista, que envolve temporalidade, e “pode ser posto como bem de privilégio temporário” [(fls. 04)](http://www.eduvaleavare.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/software.pdf).

Mas é possível que você disponibilize sua obra sob domínio público se quiser, bastando criar (e de preferência registrar junto com o programa no INPI) uma licença pela qual você renuncia a quaisquer direitos disponíveis de autor (no Brasil não tenho conhecimento de nenhum, mas um exemplo estrangeiro de software disponibilizado por domínio público é o [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite)).

## As licenças de software livre

Transitando entre estes dois extremos (licença proprietária X domínio público) está o movimento do software livre, que tem na [Free Software Foundation](https://www.fsf.org/pt-br) sua origem e expressão máxima.

A filosofia do software livre se baseia sob quatro liberdades fundamentais:

- Liberdade 0: A liberdade de executar o programa, para qualquer propósito.
- Liberdade 1: A liberdade de estudar como o programa funciona e adaptá-lo para as suas necessidades.
- Liberdade 2: A liberdade de redistribuir cópias.
- Liberdade 3: A liberdade de aperfeiçoar o programa, e liberar os seus aperfeiçoamentos.

As licenças de software livre se dividem em três grandes grupos: as <kbd>**permissivas**</kbd>, as <kbd>**recíprocas parcais**</kbd>, e as <kbd>**recíprocas totais**</kbd>.

No fundo, todas estas licenças são apenas textos que procuram padronizar a utilização de licenças de software mais permissivas do que a proprietária, e menos do que a de domínio público.

Você pode perfeitamente criar sua própria licença, utilizando ou não trechos de outras. Você pode, por exemplo, criar uma licença que seja em parte MIT, em parte Creative Commons, e ainda incluir quaisquer condições (desde que sejam válidas pelo ordenamento jurídico) que quiser.

Ou criar uma licença proprietária, e permitir apenas uma ou outra liberdade específica de utilização.

O único problema que você pode ter é se estiver utilizando outro programa base, que já tenha uma licença associada e exija que seu programa siga as mesmas regras (aqui também precisamos nos aprofundar mais).

Vejamos então, um resumo das principais licenças de cada grupo, mas ao invés de comentar cada uma, vou apenas incluir um excelente quadro criado no site [Escolha uma Licença](http://escolhaumalicenca.com.br/), o qual, à propósito, é licenciado sob a Creative Commons Atribuição 3.0 Brasil, o que nos dá o direito de fazer isso desde que informemos se houve modificação (NÃO), que informemos o crédito (checked) e um [link para a licença](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/br/).

<kbd>**Permissivas**</kbd>

São as licenças com as menores restrições, permitindo, inclusive, que trabalhos derivados sejam distribuídos por uma licença fechada. Estão entre elas:

• BSD License 9

[image: Imagem da licença BSD]

• MIT License

[image: Imagem da licença MIT]

• Apache License V2.0

[image: Imagem da licença Apache V2.0]

<kbd>**Recíprocas totais**</kbd>

São as licenças livres com as maiores restrições. Em geral, requerem que a distribuição aconteça com a mesma licença que original.

Estão entre elas:

. GPL 2.0

[image: Imagem da licença GPL 2.0]

<kbd>Recíprocas parciais</kbd>

A diferença desta para a anterior é que "se as modificações foram utilizadas como componente de outro projeto de software, este projeto não precisa, necessariamente, ser disponibilizado sob a mesma licença." (Wikipedia)

. GNU Library or Lesser General Public License (LGPL)

[image: Imagem da licença LGPL]

. Mozilla Public License 1.1 (MPL 1.1)

[image: Imagem da licença MPL]

. Eclipse

[image: Imagem da licença Eclipse]

**CREATIVE COMMONS**

As licenças Creative Commons são bastante amplas, e podem ir desde a permissão total (na modalidade `by-sa` que é semelhante a uma licença MIT), até a quase uma licença fechada (na modalidade `by-nc-nd`), permitindo apenas a distribuição, sem possibilitar nenhuma modificação ou uso comercial (também chamada de “propaganda grátis”).

Veja [aqui](https://br.creativecommons.org/licencas/) os tipos de licença Creative Commons, ou responda algumas perguntas básicas e gere uma automaticamente [aqui](https://creativecommons.org/choose/).

## Como escolher uma licença de software livre

Isto pode ser realmente muito complexo e tortuoso, principalmente se você estiver utilizando diversos códigos de base, com diversas licenças diferentes atribuídas a eles.

No entanto, [o melhor estudo sobre este tema que encontrei até agora](http://www.teses.usp.br/teses/disponiveis/45/45134/tde-14032012-003454/publico/MestradoVanessaSabino.pdf), contém um excelente fluxograma (também publicado na wikipedia), e que pode ajudar bastante na escolha:

[image: Fluxograma]

Também é digna de nota esta tabela (mesma fonte), muito útil pra analisar as diferenças e as compatibilidades entre as licenças:

[image: Tabela]

Este wiki não esgota o tema, e pretendo trabalhar mais nele futuramente, e convido a todos os interessados que puderem colaborar a que o façam sem pensar duas vezes. Lembrem-se que qualquer edição pode ser revertida, então não se acanhem em editar o que considerarem impreciso/incorreto.

## **Fontes:**

### Imagens:

- [http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d4/Mecanismo_de_seleção_3.png](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d4/Mecanismo_de_sele%C3%A7%C3%A3o_3.png)
- [http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licença_de_software_livre](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licen%C3%A7a_de_software_livre)

### Artigos:

- http://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=30131
- [http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licença_de_software_livre](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licen%C3%A7a_de_software_livre)
- [http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domínio_público](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dom%C3%ADnio_p%C3%BAblico)
- http://www.infowester.com/freexopen.php
- http://sejalivre.org/voce-conhece-as-licencas-de-software-livre-ja-esta-na-hora-de-saber-ne/

Para saber mais sobre direito autoral, veja este artigo no site do ECAD:

- http://www.ambito-juridico.com.br/site/?n_link=revista_artigos_leitura&artigo_id=10902&revista_caderno=17

## Trabalhos acadêmicos:

- http://ccsl.ime.usp.br/files/relatorio-licencas.pdf
- http://direitorio.fgv.br/sites/direitorio.fgv.br/files/Manifesto%20do%20Dominio%20Publico%20-%20Portuguese%20Version_0.pdf
- http://www.teses.usp.br/teses/disponiveis/45/45134/tde-14032012-003454/publico/MestradoVanessaSabino.pdf (tese citada nos comentários da pergunta)
- http://www.eduvaleavare.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/software.pdf
- http://jus.com.br/artigos/10312/a-protecao-juridica-do-software-com-enfase-em-patente