# Plágio de código

Tags: licença

No mundo acadêmico, o plágio e a referenciação são levados a sério. E quando se trata da nossa criação intelectual, até que ponto seria plágio copiar e colar trechos de outro código, disponível na internet, no meu?

Particularmente nunca referenciei os trechos de código que eu copiei. Isso é plágio? A punição legal é a mesma para o plágio do mundo acadêmico?

Comment: Não sei se é uma pergunta boa para o site, acho que é jurídica demais e pode ter muitas nuances. Essencialmente é violação de direitos, é pior que plágio, é contravenção ou crime dependendo de como se dá, além de indenização cível possível. Mas não vou entrar em detalhes porque não sou advogado.

Comment: Depende de onde você pegou o código. Abrir um fonte HTML por exemplo e copiar um trecho de código sem autorização do autor, ou sem ele ter disponibilizado com uma licença permissiva é crime de violação de direito autoral, mas se foi numa página que o autor disponibilizou para fins acadêmicos ou meramente instrutivos (tipo um blog), e não fez nenhuma ressalva de direitos reservados, aí não vejo problema, mas é preciso ficar atento, cada caso é um caso.

Comment: Aqui no SOpt por exemplo o autor de uma resposta já cede de antemão os direitos de reprodução. modificação etc... inclusive para fins comerciais, sem necessidade de citação da fonte. Mas outros sites podem ter outras politicas, como disse, é bom ficar atento. [Neste wiki](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76564/como-funciona-o-licenciamento-de-software-no-brasil) tem algumas informações que podem ser úteis.

Comment: Opa, acho que falei uma bobagem. Parece que [aqui no SOpt é preciso citar inclusive o autor da resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) etc. Agora fiquei na dúvida se isso é pra  reprodução do código em outros sites (blogs etc), ou se também é preciso citar na aplicação (no código). Será que vale um tópico no meta?

Comment: Só pra constar, [esta](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) é a licença que o  SOpt usa. Então, pelos termos (não tenho certeza absoluta, porque está em inglês) é preciso sim atribuir autoria E publicar o código pela mesma licença(!). Achei bastante restritiva, e em tese pode complicar pra quem vai usar um trecho e quer publicar o código com licença proprietária... Mas posso estar errado, quando tiver um tempo vou criar um tópico no meta pra entender isso direito...

Comment: @gustavox Não concordo com você quanto a "copiar um trecho de código sem autorização do autor ser crime de violação de direito autoral". A rigor, isto só aconteceria se a cópia fosse feita em cima de um website estático e a cópia fosse idêntica. Qualquer alteração poderia fazer o autor da alteração alegar que é um conteúdo novo produzido a partir de um conteúdo existente. [Este texto clarifica um pouco mais estes aspectos](http://dana.sh/afM75p).

Comment: normalmente quando algo possui um registro de patente, não fica "solto" livremente na internet.. o que encontra-se livremente na internet geralmente é sob licensas para uso público.. Mas note que mesmo scripts com licensas open source, deve-se respeitar os cabeçalhos, por exemplo, uma plataforma como o Magento, o código é aberto, porém, não dá o direito de qualquer pessoa trocar os dados de cabeçalhos de licensiamento. E muitos amadores fazem isso com intuito de enganar um cliente, por exemplo, como se aquele produto fosse obra dele.. Nesse caso é crime grave.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez eu citei o HTML mas talvez tenho sido um exemplo ruim, pq HTML nem código é, e por isso não consigo imaginar um caso em que copiar um trecho de HTML seja violação de direito autoral. Mas se partirmos por exemplo para javascript, que também é possível acessar simplesmente inspecionando pelo navegador, tenho certeza de que copiar o código (mesmo apenas um trecho, e mesmo modificando) é violação de direito autoral. Mas concordo com você que se a alteração for substancial, fica muito difícil de provar (o que não quer dizer que não exista a violação em si).

Comment: E tem uma grande diferença entre patente e direito autoral, o que busquei explicar naquele wiki citado acima... Simplificando, não existe patente de software no Brasil, mas existem os direitos autorais.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez só pra constar, se o autor da alteração alegar que "é um conteúdo novo produzido a partir de um conteúdo existente.", a meu ver ele estará confessando uma violação de direito autoral, porque os direitos de modificação e utilização do código são protegidos pela Lei [9610/98](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/leis/l9609.htm): Art. 29. Depende de autorização prévia e expressa do autor a utilização da obra, por quaisquer modalidades, tais como:
I - a reprodução parcial ou integral;
II - a edição; [...] .

Comment: @gustavox Bom, isto seria a lei brasileira, então. Mas pra conteúdo de internet fica meio complexo auferir plágio, não concorda?

Comment: Sim @CiganoMorrisonMendez imagino que deva ser uma guerra de peritos (imagina explicar pro juiz porque este código é cópia daquele, se ele não for exatamente igual), e vai acabar pendendo pro lado que o juiz der mais credibilidade... deve ser bem complicado, e se o cara não tiver feito o registro direito então (podendo assim provar a data de criação e/ou publicação anterior)...

Comment: @gustavox, esse é uma questão bem interessante a todos os desenvolvedores e empresas de software. Apesar de considerar a resposta do Cigano esclarecedora, seria interessante termos uma resposta com cunho legal sobre um conhecedor da legislação nacional (no caso você, hehe). Se tiver disponibilidade seria agregador a pergunta e a comunidade! =)

Comment: @Fernando acho que esta pergunta já tem a resposta possível aqui mesmo no SOpt: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76564/como-funciona-o-licenciamento-de-software-no-brasil. Mas não é uma resposta curta, nem simples. A única parte desta pergunta que acho que não está respondida no wiki é esta "Particularmente nunca referenciei as funções que eu copiei. Isso é plágio?". E isso é algo impossível de responder sem saber cada trecho de cod que o AP usou. Dá uma olhada no wiki, e se ainda achar que uma resposta aqui ajudaria mesmo, dá um toque que quando tiver um tempo tentarei elaborar algo...

Comment: Você viu a resposta de baixo, do Luiz Vieira? Ela não te agradou? Me parece que ela é absurdamente melhor. E salvou sua pergunta.

Comment: Seria interessante colocar na discussão, o que seria valido como "propriedade/trabalho", visto que em mundo de código, nem toda linha é significativa. O que seria considerado intelecto ? até que ponto uma solução poderia ser considerada propriedade. acho que isso vale apena ser discutido... não tenho uma opinião bem formada sobre isso ):

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Plágio e referenciação

Seja ou não "no mundo acadêmico", plágio e referenciação são conceitos complicados. Plágio é essencialmente você se apropriar de algo que foi feito por outra pessoa e dizer que foi você quem fez. E é algo um tanto maior do que apenas esquecer de citar uma fonte (por erro ou má fé), já que geralmente envolve o roubo de toda uma contribução (isto é, um resultado). Por isso plágio é algo tratado com rigor. Eu até acho que na indústria esse rigor é maior, porque envolve diretamente dinheiro. Isto é, na academia o plágio é essencialmente uma afronta à ética. Na indústria é, além de uma falha ética, também um impedimento para que o autor original receba os benefícios que lhe são devidos pela obra.

A referenciação é parte fundamental da ciência, em que conhecimento explícito é construído a partir de mais conhecimento explícito. Em outras palavras, um autor estuda, entende, questiona e reutiliza conhecimento formal que aprendeu de outros para avançar a ciência um pouco além da sua fronteira atual ([este post do Gizmodo Brasil](http://gizmodo.uol.com.br/o-que-exatamente-e-um-doutorado/) reproduz em português uma brilhante ilustração disso).

A engenharia, como uma "ciência aplicada", tem também o mesmo ideal. Afinal, ao construir um prédio um engenheiro não precisa explicar todas as vezes o porquê de determinado material ser suficientemente resistente para o projeto proposto. Ele pode se basear em conhecimento já bem fundamentado, muitas vezes estudados por outros, para construir outras coisas sobre aquele conhecimento já explorado. Em muitos casos, quando o conhecimento já é suficientemente bem fundamentado pra ser senso comum, a referência ao autor original sequer é necessária (você não precisa citar Pitágoras pra usar sua famosa equação no cálculo de distâncias entre objetos).

**Mas isso não quer dizer que você pode se apropriar do trabalho de outros ao fazer o seu, mesmo que derivativo e mesmo que fazendo a referência!**. O problema está justamente na *interpretação* a respeito de alguém estar ou não se apropriando do trabalho de outros.

Por exemplo, imagine um artigo científico (totalmente "academia", em que o autor não está ganhando dinheiro algum com o material) que faz menção a um livro. Algo como, por exemplo:

> "Em seu livro ['The Design of Everyday Things'](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1452654123), Donald Norman
>   introduz o conceito de Affordances no design, tratando de como
>   atributos dos próprios objetos auxiliam ou conduzem a interação com
>   eles."

Primeiramente, essa citação não reproduz nada do livro diretamente. Além disso, ela apenas apresenta uma opinião, uma interpretação do leitor (o autor do artigo) a respeito de certo conteúdo do livro. Deve ser muito claro que ela é bem diferente de uma citação assim:

> "De acordo com Norman (2002, p. 9):
>
> '*Affordances* fornecem dicas importantes sobre como as coisas podem
>   ser operadas. Pratos servem para serem empurrados. Maçanetas servem
>   para serem giradas. Vãos servem para ter outras coisas inseridas
>   neles. Bolas servem para serem atiradas ou rebatidas. Quando
>   *affordances* são usadas apropriadamente, o usuário sabe o que fazer apenas olhando: não é necessário nenhuma imagem, rótulo ou instrução.
>   Quando coisas simples precisam de imagens, rótulos ou instruções, o
>   design simplesmente falhou.'
>
> Tradução livre do original em inglês:
>
> '*Affordances provide strong clues to the operations of things. Plates
>   are for pushing. Knobs are for turning. Slots are for inserting things
>   into. Balls are for throwing or bouncing. When affordances are taken
>   advantage of, the user knows what to do just by looking: no picture,
>   label, or instruction is required. Complex things may require explana-
>   tion, but simple things should not. When simple things need pictures,
>   labels, or instructions, the design has failed.*'"

Nesse outro caso, se está reproduzindo diretamente uma parte da obra original. E ai mora o perigo.

### Uso Justo (*Fair Use*)

Existe um conceito legal chamado *fair use* (que eu traduzo livremente como "uso justo") que trata desse segundo tipo de citação. A ideia é justamente indicar quando a reprodução ou o uso de parte de uma obra original de outro alguém é feita com motivos mais "nobres" (isto é, justos).

O *fair use* indica que essa apropriação parcial é justa quando tem por objetivo analisar ou criticar uma obra, mesmo que ela seja restrita por direitos autorais:

> Uso Justo é um princípio de direitos autorais baseado na crença de que
>   o público tem o direito de usar livremente porções de materiais
>   restritos (copyrighted) para propósitos de comentário ou crítica.
>
> Tradução livre do original em inglês (do site [Fair Use](http://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/fair-use/)):
>
> "*Fair use is a copyright principle based on the belief that the
>   public is entitled to freely use portions of copyrighted materials for
>   purposes of commentary and criticism*."

Acontece que o julgamento sobre o que é uso justo ou não é *subjetivo*. O professor e seus alunos em uma faculdade podem achar justa a distribuição de 40 cópias Xerox de apenas uma página de um livro, mas o autor do livro pode achar que esse "nobre gesto educacional" o privou de receber os valores da venda de 40 livros. Se o autor processar o professor ou a universidade, o resultado vai depender do que o juiz achar.

Citando novamente a página do uso justo (e até fornecendo um exemplo de uso delicado aqui mesmo! hehehe):

> "Algumas pessoas erroneamente acreditam que é permitido usar um
>   trabalho (ou uma porção dele) se derem o devido reconhecimento à
>   fonte. Por exemplo, acredita-se que é ok usar uma fotografia em uma
>   revista contanto que o nome do fotógrafo esteja incluido. Isso não é
>   verdade. O reconhecimento da fonte do material (como a citação ao
>   fotógrafo) pode ser considerado em um julgamento de uso justo, mas não
>   irá proteger contra a alegação de violação de direitos. Em alguns
>   casos, como em propagandas, o reconhecimento da fonte pode sair pela
>   culatra, permitindo alegações adicionais como a violação do direito à
>   publicidade. Quando em dúvida sobre a permissão de uso ou o
>   reconhecimento da fonte, a mais prudente linha de ação é solicitar a
>   permissão de reprodução ao detendor dos direitos."
>
> Tradução livre do original em inglês (da mesma página citada
>   anteriormente sobre uso justo):
>
> "*Some people mistakenly believe it’s permissible to use a work (or
>   portion of it) if an acknowledgment is provided. For example, they
>   believe it’s okay to use a photograph in a magazine as long as the
>   name of the photographer is included. This is not true. Acknowledgment
>   of the source material (such as citing the photographer) may be a
>   consideration in a fair use determination, but it will not protect
>   against a claim of infringement. In some cases, such as
>   advertisements, acknowledgments can backfire and create additional
>   legal claims, such as a violation of the right of publicity. When in
>   doubt as to the right to use or acknowledge a source, the most prudent
>   course may be to seek the permission of the copyright owner*."

Assim, há que se tomar cuidado. Você não vai necessariamente ser processado se não solicitar permissão para a reprodução, principalmente se seu uso é realmente justo e se você cita a fonte. Mas se deve estar ciente de que problemas podem ocorrer, principalmente se a parte que você reproduzir é essencial do trabalho original (já teve casos de paródias - algo permitido por esse mesmo princípio de crítica ou comentário - que tiverem problemas por reproduzirem partes consideradas essenciais/marcantes de músicas ou filmes, por exemplo).

### E a reprodução de código?

Naturalmente, a reprodução total e exata de todo o código de um sistema é plágio simples é puro, e vai certamente resultar em processos pelo autor original. Mesmo os códigos com licenças abertas geralmente têm cláusulas que te impedem de fornecer o código original a terceiros (pois se intenciona preservar a fonte original, mesmo que lá o acesso seja liberado). A reprodução de partes de código aberto em um sistema maior pode ser considerada derivativa, e assim em princípio não haveria nada de errado. Ao menos, esse é o meu entendimento (e eu posso estar enganado - cautela é sempre útil pra você).

Mas mesmo a reprodução de partes de código de propriedade restrita poderia ser tratada como uso justo se:

1 - For motivo de crítica ou comentário. Você poderia postar em seu blog um pedaço de código de um sistema proprietário que encontrou para comentar sobre os brilhantes aspectos da implementação, ou sobre um tipo de erro a evitar de se cometer.

2 - Não reproduzir uma parte essencial do código proprietário. Naturalmente, se você reproduzir a implementação de um trecho de um algoritmo secreto, mesmo que seja para fins de crítica ou comentário, você pode ser processado porque esse algoritmo pode ser considerado como parte essencial do produto ou negócio do autor original.

Usar pedaços de código proprietário dentro de seu código também proprietário é errado do ponto de vista ético, mas também é algo difícil de ser impedido. Algoritmos são essencialmente ideias de resolução de um problema, e infelizmente (ou felizmente - eu sou adepto dessa visão) não se pode impedir que ideias sejam distribuídas [já que os direitos de autoria (copyright) protegem expressões (aquela particular implementação do algoritmo) e as patentes protegem invenções (algo que resolve um problema real e é fácil de reproduzir por alguém com as habilidades necessárias), mas nenhum deles protegem ideias](http://www.ipwatchdog.com/2014/02/15/protecting-ideas-can-ideas-be-protected-or-patented/id=48009/).

Isso quer dizer que se você abrir uma página de outro autor, copiar a ideia do código dele e refazê-lo do seu jeito, dificilmente você poderá ser acusado de plágio. Em alguns casos, pode até mesmo bastar alterar algumas poucas linhas para que o código seja diferente (e em caso de um eventual processo você argumente que foi uma coincidência terem usado os mesmos nomes de variáveis).

Enfim, esse assunto é complexo e ainda deve dar margem pra muitas discussões. O que eu expressei aqui é a minha interpretação com base nas fontes que eu citei. O resumo da ópera parece ser o seguinte:

- **Se o trabalho que você está criando será publicado ou colocado a disposição de outros.** Se você usa parte do trabalho de outras pessoas e não tem certeza sobre a permissão de fazê-lo (isto é, o autor não deixa claro na fonte que o trabalho é de livre acesso), é melhor tomar cuidado para que o seu uso seja justo. Isso não vai impedir você de sofrer um processo, mas aumenta as chances de que você se saia bem caso um processo seja imputado. Na dúvida, peça permissão.
- **Se o trabalho que você está criando não será publicado, será para uso próprio ou para uso de um grupo em um contexto restrito.** Nesse caso, é quase certo que ninguém saberá do seu uso do trabalho de outras pessoas. Além disso, é também quase certo que você não impedirá os autores originais de terem nenhum ganho com a obra original *em escala*. Isto é equivalente a você ler um livro e contar todo o enredo para um colega. Por ser conhecimento tácito, e não explícito, trata-se essencialmente da sua interpretação do conteúdo, da troca de ideias, e por isso não pode ser simplesmente impedido.

Answer (score 28):

### Quando se trata da nossa criação intelectual, até que ponto seria plágio copiar e colar trechos de outro código, disponível na internet, no meu (prática comum)?

Tudo depende da licença do código e de como você obteve esse código. Se o site em questão não menciona claramente algum tipo de licença, a informação é pública e não configura plágio.

Alguns tipos de licença ([como a MIT license](http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)) apenas pedem para que a licença seja mencionada dentro do código. Outras, [como a GNU license](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html), pede também para que você, ao informar que obteve certo código, informe em algum lugar que sua versão do código é modificada de outro. Ainda assim, em licenças *open source*, o código copiado não é considerado plágio justamente porque as licenças permitem isso.

### Particularmente nunca referenciei as funções que eu copiei. Isso é plágio? A punição legal é a mesma para o plágio do mundo acadêmico?

Dificilmente, a não ser que você obtenha um código proprietário e o redistribua sem modificações como se fosse seu. Neste caso, a empresa detentora do código poderia alegar plágio na justiça.

As punições são diferentes das do mundo acadêmico justamente porque *software*, *a priori*, não é uma produção acadêmica. Quando for produção acadêmica, a resposta do @LuizVieira tem uma boa explicação.

Comment: Na academia (ao menos em Ciência da Computação) também se produz software. Então, isso não é necessariamente verdade: "As punições são diferentes [...] porque sortware não é uma produção acadêmica." Acho que o ponto é mais porque os contextos de uso são diferentes, e assim os benefícios impedidos pelo plágio são diferentes (na academia, é meramente a autoria; na indústria, além da autoria, tem os benefícios financeiros também).

Comment: @LuizVieira Coloquei uma âncora para a sua resposta ;)

Comment: Obrigado. :) Mas não era bem esse o meu ponto. O que eu quis dizer é que você está certo em dizer que as punições são diferentes. Mas não é por causa de ser software acadêmico ou não, e sim pelo contexto. Ou seja, a sua resposta vale na verdade para qualquer produto (além de software). Na academia, o maior zelo é pela *ética* (na falta de uma palavra melhor), enquanto que na indústria - além da questão ética - há também a preocupação financeira. Bom, ao menos essa é a minha visão. :)