# Licenciamento de um Software

Tags: laravel, apache, licença

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que utiliza servidor Apache, Laravel, Mysql etc.

Bom, eu gostaria de licenciar este sistema, e minha dúvida é se posso fazer isto e se sim, qual tipo de licença devo usar, tendo em vista as tecnologias que estou usando terem suas licenças.

Minha intenção é licenciar como um software privado.

Agradeço.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode licenciar de qualquer forma que você quiser, pois:

- Laravel está sob a [licença MIT](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licen%C3%A7a_MIT), que permite utilizar o código em sistemas proprietários;
- Apache HTTPD está sob a [licença Apache](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licen%C3%A7a_Apache) que - embora substancialmente mais complexa que a MIT e a BSD - também permite o uso em software proprietário;
- MySQL está sob a [licença GNU GPL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License), o que *a princípio* significa que ele só poder ser combinado com outros softwares compatíveis com o GPL (e a obra derivada deve ser licenciada necessariamente sob o GPL). A palavra-chave aqui é **combinado**: simplesmente *utilizar* o MySQL - conectar-se a ele via socket, enviar comandos SQL e obter respostas - não caracteriza uma obra derivada, nem segundo a GNU nem do ponto de vista jurídico (*disclaimer*: não sou advogado).

  - Note que esse é um caso especial; no geral, se você está usando componentes GPL no seu projeto, o mesmo não poderia ser licenciado como software proprietário. Cuidado com esse "etc"...

Não se esqueça entretanto que a maioria dessas licenças exige que se atribua corretamente a fonte, e deixe claro para quem está recebendo o software os direitos que eles possuem sob o mesmo (ex.: você não pode mentir dizendo que é o autor do Laravel, nem proibir seus clientes de fazer cópias do MySQL).

Sugiro a leitura [dessa pergunta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76564/215) para uma visão mais completa do processo de licenciamento. Em particular, é preciso prestar atenção nas diferentes formas que um software interage com outros, para determinar se certo uso é ou não permitido conforme a licença utilizada. Por exemplo, se você fizer modificações no MySQL e quiser redistribuí-las, é obrigatório usar a licença GPL; e se seu sistema só funciona nesse MySQL modificado - e não no original - então ele *provavelmente* será considerado obra derivada do mesmo, e portanto também teria de ser licenciado sob a GPL (de novo, não sou advogado, mas essa é uma interpretação plausível).

Comment: Obrigado @mgibsonbr's. Sobre o etc, eh por que eu estava pensando em uma pergunta genérica em que um software eh construido em varias tecnologias com diferentes licenças. Bom, vejo que cada uma tem sua particularidade e devo analisar cada licença para ter uma resposta.