# Dúvida sobre a licença Apache versão 2.0

Tags: android, apache-cordova, plugin, app, licença

Estou desenvolvendo um app com Cordova, o app poderá ser baixado sem custos, apenas algumas funcionalidades internas terão algum custo.

Eu precisei usar este plugin https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps para manipular googlemaps, que está está sob a licença Apache v2.0.

O que é preciso fazer para poder usar este plugin com esta licença?

Answer (score 5):

A licença Apache 2.0 está na categoria das licenças permissivas, logo você pode utilizar comercialmente um código sob esta licença, mas deve obedecer alguns requisitos.

Basicamente, esta imagem do site [escolhaumalicenca.com.br](http://escolhaumalicenca.com.br/) resume aquilo que é exigido, permitido, e proibido:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste wiki tem uma reposta mais completa sobre o funcionamento das licenças de software no Brasil: [Como funciona o licenciamento de software no Brasil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76564/como-funciona-o-licenciamento-de-software-no-brasil)

E [aqui](http://escolhaumalicenca.com.br/licencas/apache/) você encontra a licença Apache v2 na íntegra (em inglês) e outros detalhes importantes.

Answer (score 3):

Apache 2.0 é uma licença que permite modificações e comércio, mas você tem que creditar o cara que criou a biblioteca.

Exemplo

*License
Copyright 2013 Jake Wharton
Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at
   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.*

Fonte: http://www.whitesourcesoftware.com/top-10-apache-license-questions-answered/