# Qual a função de uma licença open-source? Quais as principais licenças?

Tags: licença, código-aberto

Tenho pesquisado e encontrado pouco conteúdo em português sobre isso, não sei se estou procurando o termo certo por não saber muito do assunto.

Tenho algumas perguntas sobre licenças em softwares *open-source*, espero não deixar a pergunta ampla, se ficar ampla, me avisem, mas acho valido essas perguntas por se tratarem de um mesmo assunto.

- Qual é a função exercida por uma licença em um software de código aberto?
- Quais as principais delas e quais seus pontos que a diverge das demais?
- Qual(is) licença(s) é(são) mais indicada(s) para códigos *open-source* contendo direitos autorais (para proteção contra cópia)?

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76564/27190

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Qual é a função exercida por uma licença em um software de código aberto?

A mesma de software proprietário. É um instrumento legal que determina autoria, propriedade e como o software pode ser usado, modificado, distribuído, etc. Pode indicar responsabilidades também.

> Quais as principais delas e quais seus pontos que a diverge das demais?

[GPL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License), [MIT](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licen%C3%A7a_MIT), [BSD](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licen%C3%A7a_BSD) e [Apache](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licen%C3%A7a_Apache) são as mais usadas disparadamente. Algumas outras podem ser mais usadas em certas comunidades ou para certas necessidades.

> Qual(is) licença(s) é(são) mais indicada(s) para códigos open-source contendo direitos autorais (para proteção contra cópia)?

Qualquer uma acima ou outras, depende da necessidade, a pergunta é genérica demais para ser respondida apropriadamente e pode até incorrer em apenas opinião.

Tem um [site que ajuda descobrir qual é a licença mais adequada](http://choosealicense.com/).

Tem a [comparação da Wikipedia com outros exemplos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_free_and_open-source_software_licenses).

Se quer saber seriamente sobre licenças consulte um advogado especializado.

Comment: O *Choose A License* é uma excelente fonte de auxilio para isso, não conhecia, obrigado!

Comment: Tem a [versão em português](http://escolhaumalicenca.com.br/) também.