# traduzir GPL ao distribuir softtware no Brasil

Tags: licença, gpl

Como pretendo distribuir alguns utilitários meus, fiquei com essas dúvidas:

A versão em inglês da GPL tem validade em países de língua não inglesa ?

Eu preciso traduzir a GPL ao incluí-la em meu software ?

No site oficial tem o seguinte:

- https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#TOCGPLTranslations

> Há traduções da GPL para outras línguas?
>
> Seria útil ter traduções da GPL em línguas que não o inglês. As pessoas até mesmo fizeram traduções e nos mandaram. Mas isso traz um risco tão grande que não ousamos aceita-lo

Além disso:

> Uma tradução não aprovada não tem força legal, e ela deve dizer isso explicitamente

Então, fiquei na dúvida, não sei se uma licensa em inglês teria validade, e pelo visto uma licensa em português precisa ser aprovada pelo pessoal da GNU antes de ter algum tipo de validde.

O que fazer nesse caso ?

---

Encontrei esta questão: [Como funciona o licenciamento de software no Brasil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76564/como-funciona-o-licenciamento-de-software-no-brasil)

Mas ela não responde minha pergunta.

Comment: Coloca as duas, uma traduzida dizendo explicitamente que é uma tradução e que pode conter erros, e a original para ter validade legal.  Obs.: o pessoal da GNU não vai aprovar traduções para não se envolver com problemas resultantes

Comment: A GPL está redigida em inglês e atualmente nenhuma tradução é aceita como válida pela Free Software Foundation, com o argumento[1] de que há o risco de introdução de erros de tradução que poderiam deturpar o sentido da licença. Deste modo, qualquer tradução da GPL é não-oficial e meramente informativa, mantendo-se a obrigatoriedade de distribuir o texto oficial em inglês com os programas. Retirei esse texto da [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License)

Comment: isso eu já sabia, e inclusive está no texto da pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

A distro Debian apresenta o seguinte:

Esta é uma tradução não-oficial da Licença Pública Geral GNU (“GPL GNU”) para o Português Brasileiro (“Brazilian Portuguese”). Ela não foi publicada pela Free Software Foundation, e legalmente não afirma os termos de distribuição de software que utiliza a GNU GPL — apenas o texto original da GNU GPL, em inglês, faz isso. Contudo, esperamos que esta tradução ajude aos que falam o Português Brasileiro (“Brazilian Portuguese”) a entender melhor a GNU GPL.

Ou seja, legalmente a GPL só se aplica quando utilizada em inglês.

Fonte: http://www.debian.org/releases/etch/arm/apf.html.pt_BR

No site da UNB tem o seguinte:

As Fontes UnB são distribuídas sob uma licença dual. Isso quer dizer que a distribuição das fontes mantém a licença de uso original em inglês das fontes Liberation (GPLv2) e inclui uma versão alternativa da licença em português (Licença Pública UnB Fontes). Esta versão em português foi criada pois, para a lei brasileira, documentos oficiais só tem validade se redigidos em língua portuguesa.

Fonte: http://www.marca.unb.br/licensa.php

Dito isto, não precisa se preocupar, o Governo Brasileiro já tem uma versão oficial traduzida:

- www.softwarelivre.gov.br/Licencas/gnu-lesser-general-public-license

Answer (score 1):

A criação de Software Livre no Brasil foi regulamentada (não sei se o termo é adequado) em um Decreto Presidencial:

https://presrepublica.jusbrasil.com.br/legislacao/1025410/decreto-7325-10?ref=topic_feed

> O objetivo deste Memorando de Entendimento é contribuir para a redução do hiato digital por meio da promoção, nos países em desenvolvimento, do uso efetivo do software livre e aberto. Tal objetivo será realizado por meio do apoio a iniciativas de capacitação em software aberto nos países em desenvolvimento.