# Sistema para mercadinho legalizado

Tags: java, licença

Desenvolvi um sistema para mercadinho que pode servir para loja também, gostaria de saber o que fazer para tornar o sistema legalizado.

- Tenho que registrar?
- Tenho que ir na SEFAZ?
- Que documento devo levar pra onde?

Comment: Olá, notei sua pergunta a pouco, não entendo muito disto, mas creio que a pergunta seja realmente off-topic, um lugar que talvez possa perguntar (mas é em inglês) seria o https://law.stackexchange.com, no entanto acho meio improvável alguém responder lá porque não é um site ainda muito popular no Brasil, outro lugar que pode pedir uma opinião é o chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha, apesar de ser sobre programação também lá não tem regras tão estritas. Creio que só alguém com conhecimento juridico poderia ajudar, o @Bacco por exemplo.

Comment: Todavia como o colega Randrade me indicou, talvez a parte sobre licenças pode ser respondida com ajuda desta [Como funciona o licenciamento de software no Brasil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76564/3635)

Comment: Muito bom gostei!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Se *legalizar* significa poder comercializar licenças, a primeira coisa a se fazer é abrir uma empresa.

Para isso, procure um escritório de contabilidade e explique a eles o que deseja fazer. Eles tem o *know how* para criar sua empresa para que você possa comercializar softwares desse tipo (CNAE).

Você precisará categorizar seu software em algumas sub categorias (software customizável, software não customizável e etc).

Um contador irá tirar todas suas dúvidas em relação a isso.

Comment: Blz, muito obrigado!